# How to add multiple users with same login page, but differentiating roles

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to put all my different users (teachers, students, admins) in the same table but how can I differentiate between them.
When I add the relationships in this table, for example : the teachers belongs to a departement table:

```php
public function departement()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Departement::class);
}
```

And the students belongs to another table which is faculty table:

```php
public function faculty()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Faculty::class);
}
```

The problem is when I add those relationships to the users table it will add automatically to all types of users (teachers, students, admins...).

Comment: I think you can do this only with laravel `guards`, cause if you have a foreign key in your users table, like `departament_id` or `fabulty_id`, it only belongs to `departament` and `faculty`, respectively

Comment: Can you add a ER diagram please?

Comment: I'm  already using guards but with guards every user has his login page, but I want the same login page with all users and the only way is to put them in the same table!

Comment: I need more information about your database. Add a ER diagram if you can or describe it for me?

Comment: I have a class diagaram but it's in frensh

Comment: no problem for me

Comment: So users do not have a role? just that relationship to which they belong?

Comment: they don't have a role cause I'm using guards 
I want to add rles and add all users in the same table but how to differentiate them when adding relationships

Comment: @MateusJunges How can i send you the diagram ?

Comment: Add a screenshot to your question or just upload it to google drive or something and post the link here

Answer (score 1):

use where

```
public function departement()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Departement::class)->where('users.type','=','student');
}

public function faculty()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Faculty::class)->where('users.type','=','admin');
}
```

Comment: users.type = departement ??
I think the user type is a teacher or admin or student ..

Comment: This was just an example :-/